# Converting an expression to modular arithmetic automatically

Tags: expression-manipulation, modular-arithmetic

I have the expression $\frac{1}{15} \left(-(-1)^n-5\times 2^{n+2}+3\times 2^{2 n+1}+15\right)$ which I want to calculate mod *m* for a very large *n*.

My current method is to ask for this exression in **FullForm**:

```
Times[Rational[1,15],Plus[15,Times[-1,Power[-1,n]],Times[-5,Power[2,Plus[2,n]]],Times[3,Power[2,Plus[1,Times[2,n]]]]]]
```

And to conver all `Rational`s and `Power`s to `PowerMod`s manually:

```
Mod[Times[PowerMod[15,-1,m],Plus[15,Times[-1,PowerMod[-1,n,m]],Times[-5,PowerMod[2,Plus[2,n],m]],Times[3,PowerMod[2,Plus[1,Times[2,n]],m]]]],m]
```

However, this is kind of time-consuming and I'm sure there's a better way. Is there any sort of 'smart' find-and-replace function I can apply to do something like this?

Comment: *m* has about 8 digits and *n* has about $10^{18}$ digits.

Comment: But *n* can be reduced mod $\lambda(n)$

Comment: @Kuba I just found it and wrote an answer to my own question using it, right before I saw your comment. :P

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a few auxiliary functions and `ReplaceAll`:

```
power = PowerMod[#, #2, m] &;

fractionMod = Mod[Numerator[#]*PowerMod[Denominator[#], -1, m], m] &;

newThing = fractionMod[ReplaceAll[oldThing, Power -> power]];
```